# Using momentjs to format a date in a specific locale

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a global locale variable based on a user's preference. When I pass that variable to moment along with a timestamp, it still displays the date in English. I'd like it to display the date in the common format for that locale. For example:

```
moment.locale('fr');
console.log(moment(867283200, "X").format('LL')); //still outputs June 25, 1997 when it should be using French months
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would this help? http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/loading-into-browser/

Comment: That fixed the problem, thank you! I just needed to include it locally.

Comment: No problem. You should mark the answer as correct tho :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. I just needed to load the locales in the browser using the locales.min.js available here: https://github.com/moment/moment/tree/develop/min